# Why my if statement is always returning error - React Firebase

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem. My **if** statement always returns an error.
What is the problem with it? It's a simple code.

I want to compare two inputs from the database and post the first one by HTTP request.

`componentDidMount()` is only for developing purposes, to see recent results added.

```
     handleSubmit(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');

       itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
         if (this.state.testNumberCheck === this.state.testNumber && this.state.usernameCheck === this.state.username){
           return alert('udalo sie!');
         } 
         else return alert('error');
       });

     }




     render() {
       return (
         <div className='app'>
           <header>
               <div className="wrapper">
                 <h1>Sprawdź wyniki badania</h1>

               </div>
           </header>
           <div className='container'>
             <section className='add-item'>
                   <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                     <input type="text" name="usernameCheck" placeholder="Podaj numer testu" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.usernameCheck} />
                     <input type="number" name="testNumberCheck" placeholder="Numer telefonu" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.testNumberCheck} />
                     <button>Sprawdź test</button>
                   </form>
             </section>
             <section className='display-item'>
                 <div className="wrapper">
                   <ul>
                     {this.state.items.map((item) => {
                       return (
                         <li key={item.id}>
                           <h3>Numer testu: <strong>{item.user}</strong></h3>
                           <h3>Numer telefonu: <strong>{item.title}</strong></h3>
                         </li>
                       )
                     })}
                   </ul>
                 </div>
             </section>
           </div>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
   export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the full code of App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import firebase from './firebase.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      testNumber: '',
      testNumberCheck: '',
      username: '',
      usernameCheck: '',
      valueCheck: '',
      items: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');

    itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      if (this.state.testNumberCheck === this.state.testNumber && this.state.usernameCheck === this.state.username){
        return alert('udalo sie!');
      } 
      else return alert('error');
    });

  }



  componentDidMount() {
    const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('items');
    itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let items = snapshot.val();
      let newState = [];
      for (let item in items) {
        newState.push({
          id: item,
          title: items[item].title,
          user: items[item].user,

        });
      }
      this.setState({
        items: newState
      });
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className='app'>
        <header>
            <div className="wrapper">
              <h1>Sprawdź wyniki badania</h1>

            </div>
        </header>
        <div className='container'>
          <section className='add-item'>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <input type="text" name="usernameCheck" placeholder="Podaj numer testu" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.usernameCheck} />
                  <input type="number" name="testNumberCheck" placeholder="Numer telefonu" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.testNumberCheck} />
                  <button>Sprawdź test</button>
                </form>
          </section>
          <section className='display-item'>
              <div className="wrapper">
                <ul>
                  {this.state.items.map((item) => {
                    return (
                      <li key={item.id}>
                        <h3>Numer testu: <strong>{item.user}</strong></h3>
                        <h3>Numer telefonu: <strong>{item.title}</strong></h3>
                      </li>
                    )
                  })}
                </ul>
              </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Please edit the question, don't add an answer for edits.